# Построение пути для пешеходов до ближайшего метро

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, координаты

Человек вводит 2 точки ( его адрес и туда, куда он едет ). Нужно сделать так, что бы при клике на кнопку на карте показывался маршрут от 1 точки до 2 и ближайшее метро у 1 точки и 2 ( т.е. будет 2 метро на карте ). И также расстояние до этих метро

```
**UPD**: http://jsfiddle.net/hb2w4d0x/1/
```

Comment: Если верить документации яндекс карт (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/router-docpage/), они умеют строить только автомобильные маршруты. Для пеших используйте Google Maps API, где можно указывать построение маршрутов для пешехода (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#TravelModes).

Comment: @Reni обновил. Добавил ссылку

Comment: @MarkShevchenko увы, но карта гугла плохо знает россию ( про улицы ) на сколько мне известно

Comment: @MarkShevchenko вы не правы, API Яндекс.Карт позволяет строить маршруты и на общественном транспорте и пешком, в руководстве просто разобран только пример с авто: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_data_access

Comment: @KenanAivazov а почему вы не строите сразу маршрут на общественном транспорте? Из него можно получить пешеходные сегменты, [вот пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_data_access).

Comment: @Reni тз такое. Нужно именно на машине и ближайшее метро у 2 точек

Comment: @Reni. Спасибо. То, что я написал, к сожалению, написано в документации самого Яндекса: "API предоставляет возможность прокладывания автомобильных маршрутов."

Comment: @KenanAivazov Если Вам нужен город с метро, подозреваю, что это Москва, то Google знает её хорошо, возможно, не хуже Яндекса.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko верно, но это не исключает маршрутов на других видах транспорта, там же не написано "только автомобильных маршрутов" :) В любом случае уверена, что документация скоро будет обновлена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Построить маршрут от точки до ближайшей станции метро можно в два шага:

1. Определяете ближайшую станцию метро к точке через обратное геокодирование. [Пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/reverse_geocode?from=SO)
2. Строите пешеходный маршрут. [Пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_pedestrian?from=SO)

Comment: спасибо за данные ссылки! Но возникает вопрос: по такому методу он ставит метки только исходя от 1 точки. Как мне сделать так, что бы он учитывал и 2 точку? Сам понять не могу и в интернете найти не могу :C

Comment: вам нужно сделать два запроса, по одному на каждую точку